# Custom Iterator to pretend element is in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

A class of element used to be stored in a vector with other similar elements.

But now, it been removed and moved into its own field in the parent object.

```
class OldParent {
    vector<char> OldCollection = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
}

class NewParent {
    char A = 'A';
    vector<char> NewCollection = { 'B', 'C' };
}
```

The type that is held by the vector is significantly more complicated than a character, it is a vector of a normalish struct.

So the actual original type would look something like this:

```
struct ActualType {
   string val1;
   int val2;
   double val3;
}

vector<vector<ActualType>> OldCollection;

// vector that has been separated out
vector<ActualType> SeparatedCollection;
```

The problem is that alot of the original code uses iterators over the whole old collection and a clean way I thought I could implement this change would be to create an iterator that would work as if the separated field was never separated. This way much of the original code would not have to be changed.

However, I am definitely open to new ideas as well.

The use case looks like this:
The change means that one of the numbers will be permanently stored outside of the vector.

```
vector<int> nNums = {1,2,3};

void UseCase(int x)
{
    int toRemove = 0;
    for (auto& num : nNums)
    {
         if (num - x < 0)
         {
            toRemove++;
            x -= num;
         }
         else
         {
            num -= x;
            break;
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < toRemove; ++i)
            nNums.erase(nNums.begin());
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class OldParent`... What is this? C#?

Comment: @IndianaKernick oops typo.

Comment: If I understand the question right, you could create your own type and overload the common operators that an iterator would use (like * and ++). You then can say something along the lines of "if you reach the end of old collection (OldCollection.end()) then return SeparatedCollection and flip some bool. Then once you try to increment again some boolean is now true which can return OldCollection.end()". This would work but is not a clean way to fix your problem. You should probably just go through and fix the old code. Maybe also you could just use the first index of Old for Separated?

Comment: you should add how you expected to use the class/variable.'

Comment: @appleapple it's a struct stores a couple of fields.

Comment: @KyIeLiebIer ack, i'm trying a PoC on my PC and I'm seeing what you mean by this is not clean.

Comment: Note if you do create a new iterator type, it will be a different type from what existing code is using, and you will have to somehow get that code to use the new type.

Comment: @aschepler, this is exacerbated by the fact that it has to be backwards compatible as well. Such is life, I'll likely have to change the 10+ repos that are experiencing this change manually...

Comment: @winnie well, I mean how you'd **use** the structure, in **real code**.

Comment: @appleapple I'd say there are two main uses that I need to worry about have been added in the post.

Comment: @appleapple The use case is related to a fairly complex process and I'd prefer to change as little as possible so I don't mess things up somewhere that I can fathom. But, I think from writing the iterator below, I've realized that just changing the code is probably better.

Comment: From the use case: what would erasing the distinguished element mean?

Comment: @DavisHerring the distinguished element can be ignored for the most part (which is why it is now being distinguished), but it means the places where it can't get ignored are adversely effected. It would mean inaccuracy between the state of application and real life (although the distinguished element rarely occurs).

Comment: @winnie: It “rarely occurs”?  Being outside the container, it *always* exists.

Comment: @DavisHerring, the value will go non-zero like once an hour, and then go back to zero immediately on the next tick. For perspective the main vector is updated a couple times a  second minimum. Zero is used to indicate "doesn't exist" semantically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo for a custom container that will take pointers to both the separated object and the container for the rest of the objects:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
class CustomIterator;

template <typename T>
class CustomContainer
{

public:
    CustomContainer(std::vector<T> *container, T *separated) : mContainer{container},
                                                               mSeparated{separated} {}
    std::vector<T> *GetContainer() { return mContainer; }
    T *GetSeparated() { return mSeparated; }
    inline CustomIterator<T> begin() { return CustomIterator<T>(this); }
    inline CustomIterator<T> end() { return CustomIterator<T>(this, mContainer->size() + 1); }

private:
    std::vector<T> *mContainer;
    T *mSeparated;
};

template <typename T>
class CustomIterator
{
public:
    CustomIterator(CustomContainer<T> *container) : mCustomContainer{container}, mPos{0} {}
    CustomIterator(CustomContainer<T> *container, int pos) : mCustomContainer{container}, mPos(pos) {}
    CustomIterator(const CustomIterator<T> &other) = default;
    const CustomContainer<T> *GetContainer() const { return mCustomContainer; }
    const int GetPos() const { return mPos; }
    ~CustomIterator() {}

    CustomIterator<T> &operator=(const CustomIterator<T> other)
    {
        mCustomContainer = other.GetContainer();
        mPos = other.GetPos();
    };

    bool operator==(const CustomIterator<T> &other) { return other.GetContainer() == mCustomContainer && other.mPos == mPos; }
    bool operator!=(const CustomIterator<T> &other) { return other.GetContainer() != mCustomContainer || other.mPos != mPos; }

    CustomIterator<T> operator+=(const int &movement)
    {
        if (mPos + movement > mCustomContainer->GetContainer()->size() + 1)
            mPos = mCustomContainer->GetContainer()->size() + 1;
        else
            mPos += movement;
        return CustomIterator<T>(*this);
    }
    CustomIterator<T> operator-=(const int &movement)
    {
        if (mPos - movement < 0)
            mPos = 0;
        else
            mPos -= movement;
        return CustomIterator<T>(*this);
    }
    CustomIterator<T> operator++()
    {
        const auto maxSize = mCustomContainer->GetContainer()->size() + 1;
        mPos = mPos == maxSize ? maxSize : mPos + 1;
        return CustomIterator<T>(*this);
    }
    CustomIterator<T> operator--()
    {
        mPos = mPos == 0 ? 0 : mPos - 1;
        return CustomIterator<T>(*this);
    }

    int operator-(const CustomIterator<T> &other) { return std::abs(other.GetPos() - mPos); }

    T &operator*()
    {
        const auto maxSize = mCustomContainer->GetContainer()->size() + 1;

        if (mPos == maxSize)
        {
            throw "Error: index out of bounds";
        }
        else if (mPos == 0)
        {
            return *(mCustomContainer->GetSeparated());
        }

        return (*mCustomContainer->GetContainer()).at(mPos - 1);
    }
    T &operator->() { this->operator*(); }

private:
    CustomContainer<T> *mCustomContainer;
    int mPos;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> container = {5, 6};
    int separated = 4;
    auto customContainer = CustomContainer<int>(&container, &separated);

    for (auto i : customContainer)
    {
        std::cout << (i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like Kyle Liebler has brought up, this is not an elegant solution and changing the existing code is probably going to be better.